# PHP SimpleXML - xpath is not working, but in online generator it does

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have a large xml file with following example content:

```
<transferData version="1.0">
<item id="1885880" itemType="kivihomepagetransfer">
<property name="country_id">
<value>4402</value>
</property>
<property name="rc_maintenance_other"></property>
<property name="claim_right_shareholder"></property>
<property name="charges_other"></property>
<property name="investment_flag"></property>
<property name="rc_repair_need"></property>
<property name="realtycompany">
<value>Asunto Oy Aulangtie 20</value>
</property>
```

I have used the online generator for xpath

http://www.xmltoolbox.com/index.html

And I want to acces the value of the `<property name="realtycompany">`, my xpath call looks like this:

```
$path = '//item[@id="'.$itemId.'"]/property[@name="realtycompany"]/value/text()';
$company = $xml->xpath($path);
print_r($company);
```

In the online generator this is working, but with the original xml not. I am simply receiving the SimpleXMLElement Object empty. The ItemId is generated in the foreach, but it is correct.

Why is this working in the small example, but the large file it does not find anything?

I tried several other versions:

```
$path = '//item[@id="'.$itemId.'"]/property[@name="realtycompany"]/value';
$path = '//item[@id="1885880"]/property[@name="realtycompany"]/value/text()';
$path = '/item[@id="'.$itemId.'"]/property[@name="realtycompany"]/value/text()';
$path = '/transferData[@version="1.0"]/item[@id="'.$itemId.'"]/property[@name="realtycompany"]/value/text()';
```

And so on... none of them found it

Comment: If you remove `test()` works?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I tried it already without text() but its the same, the object is empty

Comment: I've edited my answer below. Your XPath is working, but var_dump/print_r isn't meaningfully showing you its contents.

Comment: Do not use `print_r` on SimpleXMLelements, use `$element->asXML('php://output');`, it shows you what it returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I figured out the problem. Your XPath is working, but var_dump/print_r isn't showing you anything useful. Try the following:

```
$path = '//item[@id="'.$itemId.'"]/property[@name="realtycompany"]/value/text()';
$company = $xml->xpath($path)[0];
print_r((string)$company);
```

---

*Earlier Response*

I haven't used XPath much, but the problem seems to be with the 'value' bit. Your XPath does return the right thing when `value` is not used.

This worked for me: *(of course, I didn't add any sanity checks before accessing array indices)*

```
<?php

$path = '//item[@id="'.$itemId.'"]/property[@name="realtycompany"]';
$company = (string)$xml->xpath($path)[0]->value;
print_r($company);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. Can you explain why are you using `[0]` in `$company = $xml->xpath($path)[0];` ? Its all so new to me and I have to build a big cataloque from this xml, so there is much information needed!

Comment: Since you're searching by @name, there is a possibility of multiple results. So, an array is returned. In your case, an array with one element.

Comment: May I note that this code will fail in PHP `5.3` and lower, instead use there `$companies = $xml->xpath($path);$company = (string)$companies[0]->value;`

Answer (score 2):

You are using the *SimpleXML*  extension and its `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` method specifically to run the xpath query.

However *SimpleXMLElement* xpath query can not return text-nodes (`text()`). In your case, even you write `text()` at the end of the xpath query, it will return the texts parent element-node.

As this is SimpleXML you only need to cast it to string / use it in string context:

```
list($company) = $xml->xpath($path);

# echo is string context and output is: "Asunto Oy Aulangtie 20"
echo "Value: ", $company, "\n";
```

If you want to retrieve the text-value as string from the document directly, you can import that into *DOMXPath* and evaluate:

```
$path = 'string(//item[@id="'.$itemId.'"]/property[@name="realtycompany"]/value)';

$xpath = new DOMXPath(dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument);

var_dump($xpath->evaluate($path)); # string(22) "Asunto Oy Aulangtie 20"
```

As the *var_dump* shows you get a string back from the *evaluate* call because the xpath query queries a string (with *`text()`* at the end you would get a *DOMText* node back, something Simplexml can not represent).

Answer (score 0):

If all you would like to access is the values of elements, it might be easier to use the [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$xml = file_get_html('file.xml');
$value = $html->find('property[name=realtycompany]');
echo $value->plaintext;
```

Comment: I don't like it, he is loading XML not HTML, using an HTML parser can cause strange bugs

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses He might like it. I use it for XML as well as HTML, the document type doesn't really matter. It's much simpler to use than than PHP's XML parsers.

Comment: but my point is that he might run into strange errors or unexpected behaviour like `<li>` elements he can't make code like `<li>:D<li>:(</li></li>` this will fail in HTML because if there is a li after another one it has to end the other, and what do you think about `<link>`? there are just too much exceptions in HTML